# Possible to call an Objective-C method from Javascript in a Webview?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call an Objective-C method from Javascript in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733676/how-do-i-call-an-objective-c-method-from-javascript-in-uiwebview)

I have a WebView, and I want to call a view in Objective-C from JavaScript. Does someone know how I can do this?